# SPA and simple backend on same origin with Oauth2 - way to use http session

Tags: spring, cookies, oauth, oauth-2.0, okta

Using simple backend (eg Spring) and SPA front and OAuth2 auth provider, what is the correct way to implement authorization based on http sessions?

With term "correct" I mean a way to impersonate user to backend for obtaining session cookie.

Unfortunately, there is "scallable, restful, stateless" JWT hype all around. But my application will be used by very few users and it just requires plain old good security that is provided by http sessions out of the box. Current "proposed" by Okta solution is causing each request to API be verified, so each call has a significant overhead, which leads to sloppy performance.

Suppose that we have SPA app exposed on myapp.com and its backend is exposed on proxy via myapp.com/api.

What I'm thinking of is implementation of this scenario:

1. user visits the SPA (Angular, React, whatever)
2. SPA calls backend for user details, 403
3. SPA is redirecting to oauth provider, eg. Okta
4. user logs on to oauth provider
5. oauth provider grants bearer token and redirects back to SPA
6. SPA calls backend for user details, but with bearer now
7. spring recives oauth2 granted token, verifies this within oauth provider, creates http session and grants session cookie (JSESSIONID)
8. SPA calls to backend are automatically filled with cookie (we are talking to proxy so it's this same domain)

or maybe:

1. user visits the SPA (Angular, React, whatever)
2. SPA calls backend for user details, 403, so backend is redirecting to oauth provider, eg. Okta
3. user logs on to oauth provider
4. oauth redirects back to backend with oauth2 token
5. spring recives oauth2 granted token, verifies this within oauth provider, creates http session and grants session cookie (JSESSIONID), and redirects to SPA
6. SPA calls backend for user details (automatically filled with cookie), 200

Is there out-of-the-box available configuration out there? It looks like both scenarios are requiring a lot of work and configuration on spring-security side. Sadly, it's hard to find any resources related with http session cookies combined with SPA and oauth2 providers.

Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster implements the (more secure) second scenario (also known as authorization code flow). Its implementation is based on Spring Security’s OAuth support.

We’ve tested everything with Keycloak and Okta, but it should work with any OIDC-compliant IdP.

http://www.jhipster.tech

Comment: Thank you! I had to remove all jhipster bloatware but it's working like a charm!

Comment: @MGorgon that's exactly what I'm looking for... I'm pretty sure that it'll work in the production environment as everything is behind the "same host", but how are you dealing with development where they are in 'different hosts"?

Comment: @Giovane you can use proxy for development environment aswell - for example, by use of npm